# Pandas create bar chart using 3 dataframes

Tags: pandas, grouped-bar-chart

On Pandas, I have created 3 results dataframes ( df1, df2, df3) and I would like to create a bar chart to display the sum of unique values in a specific column for each data frame.

In the Y- i would like to see the sum of unique values ( most likely would need value_counts())
in the x - df1, df2, df3 ( the categories)

Any suggestion please?

df1 [represents data in system 1] = {Process, Activity, UniqueIDs, Data Field name}
df2 [represents data in system 2]= {Process, Activity, UniqueIDs, Data Field name}
df3 [represents data in system 3]= {Process, Activity, UniqueIDs, Data Field name}

What I would like to plot is a grouped bar chart with the X representing the system type, and the y- the sum of unique IDs for the specific system

Comment: Please add a minimal example of your data.

Comment: df1 [represents data in system 1] = {Process, Activity, UniqueIDs, Data Field name}
df2 [represents data in system 2]= {Process, Activity, UniqueIDs, Data Field name}
df3 [represents data in system 3]= {Process, Activity, UniqueIDs, Data Field name}

What I would like to plot is a grouped bar chart with the X representing the system type, and the y- the sum of unique IDs for the specific system

Comment: When folks ask for a minimal example of your data, we don't just mean what are the columns, but some actual data; can you give us 5 rows of each dataframe as well (or if it is sensitive data, can you mock up 5 rows of each dataframe)? That makes it easier for someone trying to help to just copy-paste that data into python for themself, and if it is easier for us to do that, it is easier to help. Check out these two links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example